# Why does resizing images end up changing the channels as well?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, tensorflow2.0

so I have this code in python using TensorFlow which opens an image and resizes it:

```py
def parse_image(filename):
    label = filename
    image = tf.io.read_file(path+'/'+filename)
    print(image.shape)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [340, 340])
    print(image.shape)
    return image, label
```

When I open a test grayscale image using OpenCV:

```py
img = cv2.imread(path+"/test.png")
print(img.shape) #returns (2133,3219,3)
```

But when I call the above function on the same image:

```py
image, label = parse_image('test.png')

print(image.shape) #returns (340,340,1)
```

I know the 340 x 340 is the width and height I just set but why did the channels change? I'm trying to calculate the structural similarity but the test image and the image I want to compare have different channels which raises an error. The worst part is, it's this specific test image. Other grayscale images work fine.

Comment: `resize(image, [340, 340])` you might need to specify the third dimension here. I'm just spitballing, but I can imaging that unspecified dimensioned should be collapsed by default

Comment: @PaulH I tried but it raises an error. Looking at the documentation, it says:

size = A 1-D int32 Tensor of 2 elements: new_height, new_width. The new size for the images.

Comment: Please confirm that the shape after `decode_png` (but before `resize`) contains three channels.

Comment: @xdurch0 No it's still 1 channel. For this specific test image though. Another greyscale image I tested does have 3 channels.

Comment: Python uses images in BGR format. Does TensorFlow use them the same or in RGB format. If in RGB format, then that would be the cause. You need to convert back and forth. I believe TensorFlow is compatible with PIL, which uses RGB format and not OpenCV BGR format.

Comment: @locke then the problem is with `decode_png`, not `resize`. Note `decode_png` supports a `channels` argument that you can specify (try setting to 3).

Comment: @xdurch0 That solved it! Thanks :)